# Unable to resolve reference on git fetch origin

Tags: git, github

When I try to update my local code base with `git fetch origin` I get this error. Do I need to delete local branch and try again?

```
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/CICO-20404: Success
From github.com:**********/***
 ! [new branch]      CICO-20404 -> origin/CICO-20404  (unable to update local ref)
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried `git gc --prune=now` (suggested by colleague) and now it at-least finish the fetch before showing the error.

Can anyone explain what the heck is going on.

Comment: try `git fetch origin -f`

Comment: I suspect if that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found the issue. The actual branch name created by the author was `CICO-20404->master`, representing that this branch is created to safely merge the branch into master (after resolving conflicts).

Now there a `>` character in the name which is not allowed but you can force git to create such a branch if you put it inside double quotes:

`git checkout -b "CICO-20404->master"`

Once you push this branch to repo all hell breaks loose with others who update their locals. I ended up deleting local branch and also on the repo and ask everyone to update their respective locals.

Problem solved. Thank you all who responded!